# iPad is crushed, how to access iCloud backup?

Tags: icloud, backup

My iPad was recently destroyed. There were a lot of pictures on it I would like to retrieve. I did have iCloud turned on. How can I access that backup and retrieve my pictures?

Comment: it depends how you are planning to access or retrieve the backup. is it another ipad, a computer?

Comment: It will be another iPad.